# trasnsaction not confirmed forever at polygon mumbai

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testnets, polygon

since a few weeks, I tried deploy contract on polygon mumbai by hardhat. but transcaction not confirmed for a while then timed out. so I set higher gas, gasprice, and time out limit. but nothing changed.
I also tried on remix then contract deployed but It takes 380 confirmation at just one contract.
plz give me some advice.
[image]

[image]

Comment: whats your address?  Do you get a failing txn or nothing at all?  And no idea what good gas should be on Mumbai, but it might be higher (I know some networks have a 30gwe min)

Comment: @thefett thanks for your answer. I raised gasprcie to 50gwei, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Polygon (and mumbai) apparently have a min gas fee now:  https://thedefiant.io/polygon-transaction-fee-hike

Raise it up and you should be good